# I want to run the same macro on a selection of worksheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This code successfully performs calculations on one of the worksheets in my workbook

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range, j As Long, k As Long
j = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
'changing the first value of k stops it adding up columns not required

For k = 8 To j - 1
Set r = Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
Next k


End Sub
```

However I want the macro to run the same procedure on a selection of worksheets in my workbook. I found some code to 'wrap around' my existing code to allegedly perform the same procedure on each of the selected sheets but unfortunately it only performs the calculations on the sheet that is active at the time. So here is the code I am using (I am new to VBA)...

```
Sub test()


Dim WkSheets As Variant, SheetName As Variant, ws As Worksheet

'** SET The Sheet Names - MUST Reflect Each Sheet Name Exactly!
WkSheets = Array("Amazon DE FBA", "Amazon Fr", "Amazon Japan", "Bol", "CDiscount", "EBAY4", "Fragrancia")

For Each SheetName In WkSheets

    MsgBox SheetName

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = SheetName Then



Dim r As Range, j As Long, k As Long
j = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
'changing the first value of k stops it adding up un-needed columns

For k = 8 To j - 1
Set r = Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
Next k


'End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all `Range` and `Cells` calls need to be *qualified* with the `Worksheet` in question in these lines, otherwise they implicitly refer to the `ActiveSheet`.

```
j = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
...
Set r = Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
```

That is easily done with a `With` statement and added periods:

```
With ws
    Dim r As Range, j As Long, k As Long
    j = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
   'changing the first value of k stops it adding up un-needed columns

    For k = 8 To j - 1
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(1, k), .Cells(1, k).End(xlDown))
        r.End(xlDown).Offset(2, 0) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r)
    Next k
End With
```

Note the periods `.` in `.Range("A1")` and `.Range` and `.Cells(1, k)`... now each of those is qualified with the worksheet in question, namely `ws`.